# VBA returning "Run-time error 91: Object variable or With block variable not set"

Tags: vba, excel

Ok, so I'm trying to make a complex geocoding script in VBA. I have written the following code and for some reason it returns an error ("Run-time error 91: Object variable or With block variable not set"). An example of a link that I use can be: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=1+Infinite+Loop,+Cupertino,+Santa+Clara,+California+95014&sensor=false".

```
Sub readXML(link As String)
Dim odc As DOMDocument
Dim lat As IXMLDOMElement
Dim lng As IXMLDOMElement

Set odc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument
odc.async = False
odc.Load (link)

lat = odc.SelectSingleNode("GeocodeResponse/result/geometry[location_type='ROOFTOP']/location/lat").Text
lng = odc.SelectSingleNode("GeocodeResponse/result/geometry[location_type='ROOFTOP']/location/lng").Text

Debug.Print lat & "; " & lng
End Sub
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Always helpful if you state exactly where your error is.  Most likely one of your xpaths is not resulting in any selected node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SelectSingleNode()` may return `Nothing`.

Never call a property (like `.Text`) on a function if the result of that function can be `Nothing`.

Do something like this to avoid this error:

```vb
Dim location As IXMLDOMElement
Dim locationPath As String

locationPath = "GeocodeResponse/result/geometry[location_type='ROOFTOP']/location"
Set location = odc.SelectSingleNode(locationPath)

lat = GetTextValue(location, "./lat")
lng = GetTextValue(location, "./lng")


' ------------------------------------------------------------------------

Function GetTextValue(node As IXMLDOMElement, Optional xpath As String = "") As String
  Dim selectedNode As IXMLDOMElement

  If xpath <> "" And Not node Is Nothing Then
    Set selectedNode = node.SelectSingleNode(xpath)
  Else
    Set selectedNode = node
  End If

  If selectedNode Is Nothing Then
    GetTextValue = ""
  Else
    GetTextValue = Trim(selectedNode.Text)
  End If
End Function
```

Comment: Same error, but in line "Set selectedNode = node.SelectSingleNode("./" & xpath)".
Also, I got a syntax error in line "If selectedNode Is Nothing", but I added "Then" and I'm not getting that syntax error anymore.

Comment: @MartinUKPL oops, there was the `Then` missing. I also moved the `./`. Try again.

Comment: Same error, but now on `lat = GetTextValue(location, "./lat")`

Comment: @MartinUKPL Impossible, especially not on this line. My code works, I've tested it. The issue must be something else.

Comment: `lat` is an object. Does it not need a `set`? `set lat = GetTextValue(location, "./lat")` ?

Comment: @Brad: In my code, `lat` is a string. So it is in the OP's code.

Comment: I don't think so. OP declares it as `Dim lat As IXMLDOMElement` which is definitely not a string. and you don't declare it at all in your code.

Comment: @Brad But he tries to *assign* a string. See the call to `.Text` he uses. But you're right, that's the immediate cause of his trouble. I overlooked that, but my point stands. He uses a function result without prior check if it is Null.

Comment: Right right, very true. I missed the call to `.Text`. yeah, can't assign `String` to `IXMLDOMElement` *and* can't assign `null` to `String`

Comment: Ok, I got it wrong while adjusting your code to mine.
As you helped me to solve this one, I only have one thing to solve - my geocoding script works for some addresses, but doesn't for other. And that happens regardless whether the XML includes `location_type` set to `ROOFTOP`. An example could be this one - http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=Bagienna+13,+88-100+Inowroc%C5%82aw&sensor=false
Could anyone please help me on that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why the spaces before /location/lat, and .Text on lng but not lat?

Comment: Sorry, I've made those mistakes while copying my code to Firefox.

Comment: Ok I'd suggesting finding the line that throws this error to explore further which and why the object isn't set. I notice you are not specifying MSXML2 on Dim as well as Set.

Answer (score 0):

This always happens to me when I try to assign a value to an object without using `set`.  Try this:

```
Set lat = odc.SelectSingleNode("GeocodeResponse/result/geometry[location_type='ROOFTOP']/location/lat").Text
Set lng = odc.SelectSingleNode("GeocodeResponse/result/geometry[location_type='ROOFTOP']/location/lng").Text
```

Comment: A node's `.text` property returns a string, not an object.

Comment: Ahh, missed the old "need to read to the end of the line" chestnut.  Whoops!  Thanks for the note.